# How to connect vertices of two grids efficiently?

Tags: vertices

There 2 grid meshes as in image1. They both are relatively distorted.

[image: Image1]

Now how to connect the vertices from one mesh grid to its partner in the next mesh grid as in image2.
[image]

I used "Bridge edge loops" method but for a huge grid it is not easy to employ that method. Is there any other way to do it efficiently.Looking for your valuable suggestions. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the topology of each layer is the same (or close to same) you could use extrude and snapping. While a normal extrude will only extrude the outer shape of the selection, there is also the option of extruding individual faces, edges or vertices. If you only want edges linking each layer you can extrude individual vertices and if you want internal faces you want to extrude individual faces, then by using snapping you can align the extrusion to the next layer even if they are not directly aligned.

Instead of using <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude you use <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> which offers a menu -

[image: extrude menu]

By enabling [transform snapping](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/snap.html#transform-snapping) (or holding <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> while moving) you can align the extrusion with the next layer, even if they are misaligned.

[image: snapping in progress]

Then repeat this for each layer. As you extrude and snap you will get duplicate vertices on each layer, so once all the layers have been done you can select all the vertices and use <kbd>W</kbd>*->[remove doubles](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html#remove-doubles)*. If there is a small variation between layers you can try increasing the merge distance.

Answer (score 3):

Select boundary loops, which actually will be used anyway afterwards, and proceed with *Bridge Edge Loops*.

1. Select all the geometry of both grids.
2. In 3D View header menu choose *Select* > *Select Boundary Loop* (or find it from <kbd>Space</kbd> menu).
3. Once boundary loops selected it's time to connect them. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> >  *Bridge Edge Loops*.

   [image: bridging grids GIF]

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering how to connect the remaining inner vertices

Comment: @Boomi It seems I hurried too much to add that, this of course isn't the solution. You should stick with answer of sambler then. Note that if topology of second grid isn't important very much you could delete it and extrude new one from the first.